# How to play with ptrace on x86-64?

Tags: c, linux, x86-64, ptrace

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6100), and modified a little for `x86-64`(basically replace eax to rax,etc) so that it compiles:

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main()
{   pid_t child;
    long orig_eax;
    child = fork();
    if(child == 0) {
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
        execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
    }
    else {
        wait(NULL);
        orig_eax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                          child, 4 * ORIG_RAX,
                          NULL);
        printf("The child made a "
               "system call %ld\n", orig_eax);
        ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child, NULL, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't actually work as expected, it always says:

```
The child made a system call -1
```

What's wrong in the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ptrace returns -1 with errno EIO because what you're trying to read is not correctly aligned. Taken from ptrace manpage:

> ```
>    PTRACE_PEEKUSER
>           Reads a word at offset addr in  the  child's  USER  area,  which
>           holds the registers and other information about the process (see
>           <sys/user.h>).  The word  is  returned  as  the  result  of  the
>           ptrace()  call.   Typically  the  offset  must  be word-aligned,
>           though this might vary by architecture.  See  NOTES.   (data  is
>           ignored.)
> ```

In my 64-bits system, 4 * ORIG_RAX is not 8-byte-aligned. Try with values such 0 or 8 and it should work.

Answer (score 6):

In 64 bit = 8 * ORIG_RAX

8 = sizeof(long)